# Run-time error "1004: Application-defined or object-defined error" while adding hyperlink with file open dialog

Tags: vba, excel

The general thrust of what I'm trying to do here is to write a VBA macro for an excel form that uses the File Pick dialog ("Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)", specifically) to create a hyperlink in the active cell.  I'm doing it this way so I can use parameters like ".InitialFileName" in order to bring users right down to the folder where I mean for them to link from.  The intended audience here isn't 100% computer-savvy, and I don't expect even mediocre things from them.

Trying to do a lot of the "heavy lifting" for them, so the results of this are consistent.

Anyway, the code:

```
Sub InsHyperlink()
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveCell

Set ws = Sheets("Log")

Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim selectedPaths() As String
Dim I As Integer

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

With fd
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Select your File(s)"
    .InitialFileName = "\\CMI-FILE\tsk_SeamSpotWeld_TestLog _        
    \CompletedTestForms\"
If .Show = -1 Then
    ReDim selectedPaths(.SelectedItems.Count - 1)
    For I = 0 To .SelectedItems.Count - 1
        selectedPaths(I) = .SelectedItems(I + 1)
        With ws
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rng, Address:=selectedPaths(I), _
        TextToDisplay:="File Link"
        End With
        Next I
    End If
End With

Set fd = Nothing

End Sub
```

The problem of course is the error that starts this question,

> 1004, application defined or object-defined error

While testing this on my own machine, this didn't crop up at all.  It was only when I moved it to the machine that would be performing the operation that I saw this.

I've since tried two different versions of the above code, both of which run fine on my machine, but error out on the target machine in the same way.  Both times it points to the line beginning with `.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rng`

I've read through a lot of error threads starting with this, but I get the sense that the error itself is very general.  Most of them suggest defining the range as something more specific.

And of course, the problem is that I ~need~ the reference to be dynamic- the address of the cell the user currently has highlighted, so...  that solution really isn't workable- unless there's something I'm not understanding here.

Comment: Can the other user access the file(s) manually? You have also set `.AllowMultiSelect = False` which will mean user can select only one file. It is corrected in the posted answers though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this, it works quite ok for me:

```
Option Explicit

Sub InsHyperlink()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets(1)

    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim selectedPaths() As String
    Dim I As Long

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    With fd
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Title = "Select your File(s)"
        If .Show = -1 Then
            ReDim selectedPaths(.SelectedItems.Count - 1)
            For I = 0 To .SelectedItems.Count - 1
                selectedPaths(I) = .SelectedItems(I + 1)
                With ws
                    .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Cells(I + 1, 1), _ 
                               Address:=selectedPaths(I), TextToDisplay:="File Link"
                End With
            Next I
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Take a look at the `rng`. I am using. `ws.Cells`, to make sure that it gives different ranges every time.

Comment: Errors out at the same-ish line- where the hyperlink is added.  Like I said, this seems to work fine on my own machine, but when I involve the target machine, this happens.  Makes me wonder if there isn't a library missing or something of that nature.

Comment: @SkunkWerks7 - the easiest way is to compare the libraries on both machines - VBE>Extras>Libraries

Comment: I don't think I'm familiar with whatever console I might be viewing that from, or if I am I've never used it in that way.  Nevermind, now I am.  let's try comparing these...

Comment: Doesn't seem to be anything different in References between both machines- mine and the target machine.  I've actually been able to duplicate this behavior on machines other than the target machine as well.  Kinda stumped on why it works perfectly fine with my machine, and apparently with yours as well.

Comment: @SkunkWerks7 - that is pretty strange. Concerning the machine where it does not work - is the person behind it from a different nationality than you? If this is the case, probably he(she) has changed the regional settings somehow and it is changed (although I cannot think where the settings can be changed)...

Comment: I've been breaking my brain on this as well.  In my environ, both the working and problem machines are the same OS, same version of excel, etc.  At first glance I thought it might have been something to do with local admin privileges, but that theory fell apart when I duplicated on a second machine, with local admin.  My own users don't really have the juice to make changes, and where they have the juice, lack the know-how.

Comment: @SkunkWerks7 - have you checked on a new Excel file? It can be that the one you are checking is protected?

Comment: Well, the file is the same in all cases- being accessed from a network share by all machines involved.  It is a protected file (because I protected it and that's part of the whole effort), but it causes no issues on the machine I authored it on.  One thing I am investigating at the moment is a difference in build numbers for Office between the working machine and the non-working ones.  Perhaps it's some sort of a minute change in macro security?

Comment: @SkunkWerks7 -  `1004` is a typical error for trying to enter value in protected cell. Try to create a new Excel file on the PC and simply write the VBA code there.

Comment: I don't think I need to go quite that far, but I think you did lead me to the right answer nonetheless.  Trying some things with permissions.  Thank you very much.

Comment: In an effort to make this educational for anyone else who may have an interest, the solution as it turns out is a permissions issue.  As Vitaya indicated, this is a typical "general" error and often crops up when a cell is protected.  The cell in question isn't a locked cell, but there is a permission for 'Allow Hyperlinking' when protecting a sheet, and this needs to be enabled.  I think the reason I saw few problems with the authoring machine is for much of the time I was authoring the sheet, it was UN-protected.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the following and it also works fine, as Vityata's answer, but instead of using ws.Cells, I simply offset the rng one row down each iteration of the loop:

```
Option Explicit

Sub InsHyperlink()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Log")
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ActiveCell
Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim I As Long

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

With fd
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Title = "Select your File(s)"
    .InitialFileName = "\\CMI-FILE\tsk_SeamSpotWeld_TestLog\CompletedTestForms\"
    If .Show = -1 Then
        For I = 0 To .SelectedItems.Count - 1
            ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rng, Address:=.SelectedItems(I + 1), TextToDisplay:="File Link"
            Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)
        Next I
    End If
End With
Set fd = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, same line, same error.  As for the two-line file path, that was my mistake in transcribing.